# How do I remove the number spinner in Chrome on input[type=number]

Tags: javascript, css, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable webkit's spin buttons on input type=“number”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975769/disable-webkits-spin-buttons-on-input-typenumber)

[image: Example]

I want to replace the Chrome's spinner UI with something nicer. I would set the text to type=input but then I loose the specialized keyboard in iPhone. Anyone know how to disable chrome's UI treatment?

```
<input type="number" />
```

Comment: +1 for Frederic, tested the code in the duplicate and it still works, although it crashes Chrome 8 dev like crazy, it works fine in chromium 9.