# iPad HTML5 default keyboard to symbol view?

Tags: ios, ipad, html

I have a data entry form in a HTML5 application that users will be filling in on an iPad 2.

Is there any way to make the iPad keyboard default to the "Symbols" view (i.e. the keyboard with the numbers `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0`)?

They will only be entering numbers in these fields, and it's quite frustrating every time you hit "next" it reverts back to the QWERTY view.

You could do this on the iPhone by using some `-wap` CSS, but it doesn't work on the iPads unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this myself, but according to [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/InputTypes.html) this should work:

```
<input type="number">
```

Comment: That simple - who'da thunk. Thanks! Too bad it breaks all my `type` attribute validation, but that's easy enough fixed.

Comment: Yeah, just change back to what you want `onblur`.

Answer (score 11):

[Wossname's solution above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6181942/1149266) works well, but if you are also using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4812443/1149266) to hide the spin buttons that Webkit add to `<input type="number" />` in desktop Safari, it will also disable the `placeholder` attribute in desktop Safari.

Using `type="text" pattern="[0-9]*"` instead of `type="number"` seems to fix both of these issues.