# HTML inputs in Blackberry have different width depending on their type

Tags: css, html, blackberry, webkit

Inputs with styles `width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;` of type `number` or `date` have a different width than the ones of type `text` when I test the following code in Blackberry. I have checked it for simulators 9380, 9810 and 9850 and in 9810 device.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #inputsTest { 
        border: 1px solid red; 
        margin: 15px; 
    }

    #inputsTest input { 
        border: 1px solid green; 
        width: 100%; 
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
        box-sizing: border-box; 
    }
</style>

<div id="inputsTest">
      <label for="test1">Text</label>
      <input id="test1" type="text"/>
      <label for="test2">Number</label>
      <input id="test2" type="number"/>
      <label for="test3">Date</label>
      <input id="test3" type="date"/>
</div>
```

This is a screen capture from Firefox:
[image]

And this is how it looks in Blackberry (the width difference is visible in the red circles):
[image]

Code is also available here: http://jsfiddle.net/GXfXG/5/

Comment: There might be default right-padding in the BB CSS. Try setting the padding to zero.

Comment: I already tried that. The inputs become a little wider with `padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px` but still sorter than the input of `type="text"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this issue adding this CSS, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4812443/1047055) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7148952/1047055):

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=date]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```