# Rails 3 - Make text field accept only numeric values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, form-helpers

How do I make a text field accept only numeric values? If I press a letter or a symbol, the text field should not be filled, it should only allow numbers.

Is there a rails way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On the server side validate numericality:

```
class SomeModel
  validates :some_column, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}
end
```

and on the client side, add an input mask via javascript https://github.com/ruoso/jquery-regex-mask-plugin

```
$('#some_input').regexMask(/^\d+$/);
```

Answer (score 36):

Use `number_field_tag`, this will generate a HTML5 number field

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/number_field_tag

Comment: Here's how you hide the steppers in webkit based browsers. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4812443/902968

Comment: Unfortunately HTML5 number fields are broken in some browsers. If you type a non-numeric char, it *will* display it, and adding injury to insult, it will set the value to *blank*, so your JS and/or server won't even see what the user typed in. See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=304455 and https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2144

Answer (score 1):

@clyfe's answer is good, but that plugin doesn't work with HTML5 `type=number` elements. Here's some quick jQuery code that only allows integers:

```
  $("input[type=number]").keypress(function(event) {
      if (!event.charCode) return true;          
      ch = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
      return (/[\d]/.test(ch));
  });
```

to allow decimals or commas, make the regex look more like those in the plugin, e.g. https://github.com/ruoso/jquery-regex-mask-plugin/blob/master/regex-mask-plugin.js#L8 :

```
/^((\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*(((\,\d{0,2}))|((\.\d*)?)))|(\d+(\.\d*)?))$/
```

(Note that different locales have different conventions for decimals and commas, so it's probably safer to just allow digits :-)

Note also that this is a workaround for the Chrome bugs mentioned here:

- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=304455
- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2144

Comment: I asked this question 4 years ago and @clyfe's answer was what I needed... maybe your answer is usefull for people working now with rails and html5