# Ruby ActiveRecord: validate format of an integer field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to validate the format of a field in an ActiveRecord. I want this field to either be empty, or contain a sequence of digits only (it is containing an optional port number for a database connection). I'm currently trying this:

```
validates_format_of :port, with: /\A[0-9]*\Z/, message: 'Only numbers allowed'
```

but without luck. I've found that adding a required number by using for example {1, 6} sort of works, but makes the field mandatory.

Any advice?

Many thanks in advance,

Joseph.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3 - Make text field accept only numeric values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481132/rails-3-make-text-field-accept-only-numeric-values)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking to validate so that only numbers are allowed, then you should be able to use this:

```
validates :port, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}
```

Comment: That works like a charm, thanks! Added `allow_blank: true` to complete the validation.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try to validate the numericality of the field, like so:

```
validates_numericality_of :port, :only_integer => true
```

:only_integer will ensure that the value entered for :port is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just add `allow_blank: true`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax as well

```
validates numericality: :only_integer
```