# How to change the size of the spin-buttons from an input field of type 'number' in webkit browser?

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile, webkit, web-frontend

I need to change the size of the spin-buttons from an input field of type 'number' in a webkit browser. Does anybody know how to achieve this? In my special case I use jquery mobile. maybe this helps... thnx!

edit: I think I need to specify my question in that direction that I use jquery mobile on non-mobile browsers (for a kiosk system with touch monitor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **-webkit-appearance: none;** to allow for overriding in mobile browsers.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4812443/737794

Native form elements can be annoying when trying to style cross-browser, so loads of plugins exist that replace the native elements (like spin buttons) with styleable HTML elements. Here's a lightweight plugin that replaces only the spin button elements ->

http://www.egrappler.com/contents/smartspin/demo/spinner.htm

EDIT:

As headkit mentioned, this replaces 'text' inputs, not data-type="spinbox".

Here's the plugin he mentions to replace the spinbox type ->

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-Spinbox/#

Comment: thanx for your fast answer. but I think I need to specify my question in that direction that I use jquery mobile on non-mobile browsers (for a kiosk system with touch monitor).

Comment: No worries. Did you try using it for desktop webkit? Should still allow you to change styling. Try using it with display:block then change the size.

Comment: by changing size do you mean the width/height of the input-element?

Comment: Yeah...but actually that won't be much help. Updated my answer.

Comment: nice idea to use this plugin. but jQuery mobile is generating a input type 'number' when you add a slider element. your plugin uses input type 'text' - so I can't make it work...

Comment: yea - it could or should - not working. throwing errors (TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'a.mobile.behaviors.addFirstLastClasses'))

Comment: Hmm. I think the addFirstLastClasses function just adds classes to the first and last elements, so I would maybe guess that when this runs the form elements aren't loaded in the DOM. Did you add the scripts in the same order as the example?

Comment: hey, that sounds right. but yes, I loaded it in the correct order.