# Disable webkit's spin buttons on input type=“number” in AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

This may sound like a duplicate question, as the answer for 'normal' Bootstrap seems to be

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

as explained in [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975769/disable-webkits-spin-buttons-on-input-type-number).

This doesn't work for AngularJS though. Does anyone have a Solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this works for both firefox and chrome

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}

input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
```