# JS validation for restricting only numbers in textfield

Tags: javascript

We have a magento e commerce site.

we need validation support for following code **with only numbers**

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="limit(this);" onkeyup="limit(this); "title="<?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?>"
 name="billing[postcode]" id="billing:postcode" 
 value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getPostcode()) ?>"
 class="input-text validate-zip-international
 <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>" placeholder="Postal code"/>
```

**JS**

```
function limit(element)
    {
        var max_chars = 6;

        if(element.value.length > max_chars) {
            element.value = element.value.substr(0, max_chars);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Now its restricting only for numbers , but when we enter the alphabets , **cursor is moving up** . also i want to **remove the increment button present at the last**

Comment: Why don't you use a `<input type="number" max="999999" min="0" />`?

Comment: You can use `input type="tel"` also for numeric validation you can use following regex: `/^\d$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you use Validation from 
http://www.formvalidator.net/#default-validators_numbers
Example

```
<!-- Any numerical value -->
<input type="text" data-validation="number">

<!-- Only allowing float values -->
<input type="text" data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="float">

<!-- Allowing float values and negative values -->
<input type="text" data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="float,negative">

<!-- Validate float number with comma separated decimals -->
<input type="text" data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="float" 
         data-validation-decimal-separator=",">

<!-- Only allowing numbers from 1 to 100 -->
<input type="text" data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="range[1;100]">

<!-- Only allowing numbers from -50 to 30 -->
<input type="text" data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="range[-50;30],negative">

<!-- Only allowing numbers from 0.05 to 0.5 -->
<input type="text" data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="range[0.05;0.5],float">
```

Comment: i updated code in question and  Now its restricting only for numbers , but when we enter the alphabets , cursor is moving up . also i want to remove the increment button present at the last

Comment: input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
}

Comment: can you please add your code in my code and edit your answer

Comment: @beshoy semsem, are you sure                                                                             <!-- Only allowing numbers from -50 to 30 -->
<input type="text" data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="range[-50;30],negative">  is correct, because I was trying to add a validation that allows all positive numbers and only -1 as negetive number. I used allowing="range[-1;9999],negative", but doesnt seem to work in the way intended

Answer (score 2):

Change your `limit` function so it could validate input for numbers only:

```
function limit(element)
{
    var max_chars = 6,
        regexp = /^\d+$/gs;

    if(element.value.length > max_chars) {
        element.value = element.value.substr(0, max_chars);
    }
    if (!regexp.test(element.value)) {
        alert("Only numbers!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

> The **test()** method executes a search for a match between a regular
>   expression and a specified string. Returns true or false.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Comment: i updated code in question and  Now its restricting only for numbers , but when we enter the alphabets , cursor is moving up . also i want to remove the increment button present at the last

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 supports `type="number"`, change  `type="text`" to `type="number"`

Comment: What if his clients are on IE6, for example?

Comment: i updated code in question and  Now its restricting only for numbers , but when we enter the alphabets , cursor is moving up . also i want to remove the increment button present at the last

Comment: @PhiterFernandes You are still supporting people on IE6? Man, I don't want to do your job.

Comment: @BabyinCoding, use this to remove the incrementing part http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975769/disable-webkits-spin-buttons-on-input-type-number