# How do I hide input[type=time] spinner icons in Chrome?

Tags: css, html

I try to get rid of the spinners for a `input[type=time]` element in Chrome.

[image: time input with spinners]

I tried the same as for `input[type=number]` and it works:

```css
input[type=time]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=time]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="time">
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975769/disable-webkits-spin-buttons-on-input-type-number?rq=1

Comment: It's working on my machine (Chrome 57).

Comment: Shows up without spinners for me. Is another style maybe overriding this somewhere else?

Comment: Working perfectly fine without spinners for me on Chrome 64.

Comment: Uhm, thanks :-) I missed something while using postcss :-) Thanks!

Comment: Works perfectly well for me in Chrome, and Chromium, 70.x, both running on Ubuntu 18.04.