# How can I delete the arrow textfield number?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I delete the arrows of a textField number?

this doesn't work:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    const theme = createMuiTheme({
    MuiInput: {
      root: {
        "&::-webkit-outer-spin-button, &::-webkit-inner-spin-button": {
          "-webkit-appearance": "none",
          display: "none"
        }
      }
    }
    })
```

by mean this question this should work, but in my case no

[Disable webkit's spin buttons on input type="number"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975769/disable-webkits-spin-buttons-on-input-type-number)

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

my textfield is

```
<TextField
       InputProps={{ classes: { input: classes.inputStyle } }}     
       size="small"
       type="number"
```

but when i've applied my textField grow too much, i want to size be small

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS approach is right. this style should be applied to the `input` element and to apply the styles to the input element, target the `input` class instead of `root`. And another issue is here you're trying to use `makeStyles` and `createMuiTheme` at once which is not right.

To style using `createMuiTheme` this is the way:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiInput: {
            input: {
                "&::-webkit-outer-spin-button, &::-webkit-inner-spin-button": {
                    "-webkit-appearance": "none",
                    display: "none"
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And then wrap your app within `<MuiThemeProvider>`.

To do this using `makeStyles`:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    inputStyle: {
        "&::-webkit-outer-spin-button, &::-webkit-inner-spin-button": {
            "-webkit-appearance": "none",
            display: "none"
        }
    }
}));
```

And then target the `input` class by using `InputProps` prop.

```
export default function TextStyle() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div>
            <TextField
                InputProps={{ classes: { input: classes.inputStyle } }}
                type="number"
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Here is the working demo:
[image: Edit inputStyle]

Comment: but when i've applied my textField grow too much

Comment: I guess, some other class might be getting overridden. Because the demo is working fine...

Comment: i tried to change to length in your demo but  never change, i tried with size="small"

Comment: actually, width doesn't change with the `size` prop, only height. I've created two texfields with the `small` size and `medium` size and they have the difference in their height. for width try giving them style using className