# What is a role of input with type number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility, react-testing-library

I am using react testing library and by its conventions, elements should be accessed by [`getByRole`](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/byrole/).

When I had input `type="text"` the role was `textarea` which was fine.

Now I have input with `type="number"` and the error message suggests I use `spinbutton` as the role which works but it doesn't make sense to me.

Is there a different role for input with `number` type?

Comment: You can remove spin button Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975769/disable-webkits-spin-buttons-on-input-type-number

Comment: If you don’t want a spinbutton, it is quite likely that [you are not using the correct input type](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#when-number-is-not-appropriate). Is your input actually a (floating point) number? or does it merely consist of numbers? If it’s the latter, you would want to use `inputtype=numeric pattern=[0-9]*`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [MDN on `<input type="number">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#accessibility):

> The implicit role for the  element is spinbutton.

So as long as you didn't change the role by means of a `role` attribute, this is the correct role to use in `getByRole('spinbutton')`.

An input `number` is like a counter, so it is spinning its values up and down by clicking in the spin buttons on the right side or the keyboard arrows, (even its pseudo elements are `::-webkit-inner-spin-button, ::-webkit-outer-spin-button`).

If this is surprising to you, that input type might not be the right choice for the form control. The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#accessibility) reads further:

> If spinbutton is not an important feature for your form control, consider not using type="number". Instead, use `inputmode="numeric"` along with a pattern attribute that limits the characters to numbers and associated characters.

[The number input has several accessibility and usability issues](https://technology.blog.gov.uk/2020/02/24/why-the-gov-uk-design-system-team-changed-the-input-type-for-numbers/) when used for anything that is not a floating point number.

#### Update (based on OP comment)

> So would userEvent.type work on it since it is a spinbutton?

Yes it will work, here is a sandbox with a basic example

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

---

```
import { render, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

it("should type a number in input", () => {
  const { getByRole } = render(<input type="number" />);
  const input = getByRole("spinbutton");
  userEvent.type(input, "123456");
  waitFor(() => expect(input).toHaveValue("123456"));
});
```

Comment: So would `userEvent.type` work on it since it is a spinbutton?

Comment: Yes it works, I've a created a basic test for  you in the answer

Comment: How do I simulate clicking the up and down arrow rather than simulating typing?

Comment: perhaps it's a useless comment, but thanks @dippas, nice answer

Answer (score 2):

I will show you how to fish. If you write this in test file

```
 screen.logTestingPlaygroundURL();
```

this will generate a URL, if you paste this to the browser, you will see the rendered component on the page:

If you click on the element, it will generate the suggested query:

[image]